# Passar para próxima linha ao ler arquivo txt em Php

Tags: php

Bom dia a todos!
Pessoal, sou relativamente novo em php, e em um dos trabalhos aqui na empresa, estou com uma dificuldade, que pode parecer simples, mas n encontrei solução nas minhas pesquisas, que é como pular uma linha em um arquivo txt.

O que quero fazer é simples, ler um arquivo txt, ao encontrar uma determinada palavra, preciso pular para a próxima linha e fazer a leitura dessas linhas, até a palavra ser encontrada novamente. Tenho mais experiência em java, e em java temos um método chamado `readLine()`, que passa automaticamente para a proxima linha. Vi que em php existe esse `readLine()`, mas não soube aplicar, ou ele é diferente do que uso em java.
Bom, agradeço desde já a ajuda e atenção.
Obrigado!

Comment: Se for um arquivo pequeno pode usar `file()` que transforma o arquivo em array então use `array_search()` ou `in_array()` para buscar o termo desejado. Tem a versão classica com `fopen()` e `fgets()`

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar a função `fgets()` para ler linha por linha como no exemplo:

```
$handle = fopen("nome do arquivo.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
    // lê a linha
}

fclose($handle);
} else {
// caso dê erro
}
```

Fonte: [How to Read a File line by line in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246597/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-in-php)

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção @Victor Gomes!
Segui seu exemplo e consigo ler linha a linha. O que eu n consigo agora é depois que eu achei a palavra que eu quero, fazer com que ele passe para a próxima linha, tipo isso: 
`while (($linha = fgets($arquivo)) !== FALSE) {

                if (strpos($linha, $palavra) !== FALSE) {

                    }`
Deu pra entender mais ou menos?

Answer (score 2):

Usando a função **readLine**, seria dessa maneira:

```
$file = '/caminho/seu_arquivo.txt';

$linha_lida = 2;
if ( file_exists( $file ) && is_readable( $file ) ) {
    echo readLine($file, $linha_lida);
} else {
    echo "$file Não pode ser lido!";
}
```

Agora para encontrar uma palavra no TXT, seria mais ou menos assim:

```
$searchthis = "palavra";
$matches = array();

$handle = fopen("/caminho/seu_arquivo.txt", "r");

if ($handle) {
      while (!feof($handle)) {
          $buffer = fgets($handle);
          if (strpos($buffer, $searchthis) !== FALSE) {
              $matches[] = $buffer;
          }
      }
  fclose($handle);
}

//mostra os resultados:
print_r($matches);
```